# What country is missing?

Tags: knowledge

What's missing?

> Russia, ___, Egypt, Kazakhstan, USA, Azerbaijan, Georgia. (In order of most commonly seen when looking this up)

Hint

> Some might debate it. Maybe some other countries like Iceland are part of the list

Hint2:

> Hint 1 is referring to tectonic plates (kinda)

Hint 3:

> It's about continents...

Hint 4

> There are 7 countries in this list that are the most commonly given when you search for this. Here are 6.

Hint 5

> There are probably around 3-10 Wikipedia articles about this

Comment: Finland, Belarus, Ukraine..? is it? your question is broad

Comment: No. How does Russia border Iceland...

Comment: As you say, one can debate it. Maybe from sea.

Comment: How is this too broad? Why dont you close the other what ___ is missing questions? Also why DV?

Comment: Am I looking for one or many countries?

Comment: I DV because I don't think it is a good puzzle. It is a quiz question at best unless there is something very clever about it which would reveal itself after the answer. But the current question does not indicate that in the slightest. Don't take this personal. Voting (up AND down) is a community tool of sorting content and not a social media type friendly pad on the shoulder.

Comment: I VTC for the reason given: the puzzle is too broad. Without the 2nd hint too many answers are possible (counting letters, finding obscure country details, doing crazy cipher maths, thinking of these countries famous artists/scientists/... Etc.) The fact is worse because the list contains only 5 entries, making it even easier to invent some connection. As a result, the puzzle becomes a mere guessing-game which is generally unwanted contend on this site (but yes, you find many such example posts on site. That does not make them any better, though)

Comment: Finally, I do not 'pick' on you. I DV and VTC other puzzles I deem as such, too. However, I don't monitor and moderate all content here on site, so I m sure there are plenty of other posts equally deserving my DV and VTC. This is not an argument to spare this one from voting, though. Votes are a community thing. It's the combined, overall vote of all that counts, not the individual opinion. That's why voting is important. UV and DV alike!

Comment: I am sure that this puzzle can be re-opened if you edit it to add a little context and make it less broad !

Comment: There are only 7 countries in this list.

Comment: I added 3 hints. Now is it too broad? (Maybe too obvious now..)

Comment: I think to make it a "good" puzzle (and not a trivia-quiz question), there needs to be anything 'fun' , 'deductive', 'interesting', 'engaging', etc. about it. Otherwise, I would lift my VTC but not the DV.  As for "broadness": A good puzzle is not-too-broad *without* hints, i.e. the main puzzle should be stated such that "VTC too broad" does not seem appropriate. Later hints can sometimes fix-up mistakes or oversights, but generally, rather edit the whole question to better format. *Hints* - be definition - shoud not be *needed*.

Comment: @BmyGuest It's astounding how many poor posts include statements like "okay, now I'm practically giving it away :P", because the OP basically just wants to play keep-away with some little trivia. They intentionally give crappy clues because they don't actually want anyone to solve it; I'm just not sure they realize what their doing, or how it drowns out the good material on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing country is

> Turkey

The connection between these countries (vis-a-vis the hints) is

> transcontinental countries, i.e. countries that exist on two continents. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transcontinental_countries

The USA's inclusion is due to

> Hawaii being considered part of Oceania.

Comment: Correct. Here are some reasons for hints: 1,2 Iceland is on two tectonic plates, it can be argued that it is transcontinental. 3/4: obvious, I guess 5. It's maybe true. I think theres one on former ones, etc